# Why is the bitwise OR operator ( | ) used when catching multiple exceptions in Java?

Tags: java, exception

I've just learned that `|` is used to catch multiple exceptions in the same block; `|` is the bitwise operator for OR. In this case, is it still used as a bitwise operator or does it have a different meaning when in context?

Comment: Why would you think it's the *bitwise* OR operator, and not the *boolean* OR operator? It's neither, it's just a syntactical construct, meaning this exception *OR* that exception *OR* ..., and is as such a very logical choice of symbol, don't you think?

Comment: But isn't the `||` used as the boolean OR operator?

Comment: That too, yes. Both `|` and `||` are boolean OR operators. I'll leave it to you to read the documentation to figure out what the difference is. Note that the same applies to the AND operators `&` and `&&`.

Comment: From what I've understood just now `|` checks both sides while `||` skips the second if the first is true. But why would we use `|` with exceptions if `||` is the same *and* a bit faster (as it skips the second if the first exception is returned)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> In this case, is it still used as a bitwise operator or does it have a different meaning when in context?

It has a different meaning - although it's of the same "flavour" in that it's "if exception X is caught, or exception Y is caught, or exception Z" is caught.

In the [JLS section 14.20](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20) the `|` is just included literally in the grammar - it's not the OR operator in this context.

Comment: Thanks! Is this similar to how the `+` operator works; when it's used in Strings, it concatenates, while with numbers it adds them - technically it's adding in both cases, right?

Comment: @platelminto: Not quite - the + operator is still a binary + operator in the normal syntax; it's only the operands that make it string concatenation.